# How would you effectively test command line software, with many switches and arguments

Tags: testing, command-line, grammar

A command line utility/software could potentially consist of many different switches and arguments.

Lets say your software is called CLI and lets say CLI has the following features:

- The general syntax of CLI is: 
  `CLI <data structures> <operation> <required arguments> [optional arguments]`
- `<data structures>` could be `'matrix', 'complex numbers', 'int', 'floating point', 'log'`
- `<operation>` could be `'add', 'subtract', 'multiply', 'divide'`
- I cant think of any required and optional arguments, but lets say your software does support it

Now you want to test this software. And you wish to test interface itself, not the logic. Essentially the interface must return the correct success codes and error codes.

Essentially a lot of real word software still present a Command Line interface with several options. I am curious if there is any formal testing methodology established for this. One idea i had was to construct a grammar (like EBNF) and describing the 'language' of the interface. But I fail to push this idea ahead. What good is a grammar for in this case? How does it enable the generation of many many combinations .

I am curious to learn more about any theoretical models which could be applied to such a problem or if anyone in here has actually done such testing with satisfying coverage

Comment: Not answering your _actual_ question, but it seems to me that required arguments would include the actual values that you wanted to apply the operations to - it makes little sense to say "add two complex numbers" without supplying the actual numbers :-) Optional arguments could be algorithm selection for fast-add or safe-divide - gcc for one allows you to specify the attributes of the floating point calculations so you could do a similar thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a command-line tool as part of a product i maintain, and i have a situation thats very similar to what you describe.  What i did was employ a unit testing framework, and encode each combination of arguments as a test method.

The program is implemented in c#/.NET, so i use microsoft's testing framework that's builtin to Visual Studio, but the approach would work with any unit testing framework.

Each test invokes a utility function that starts the process and sends in the input and cole ts the output.  Then, each test is responsible for verifying that the output from the CLI matches what was expected. In some cases, there's a family of test cases that can be performed by a single test method, wih a for loop in it. The logic needs to run the CLI and check the output for each iteration.

The set of tests i have does not cover every permutation of arguments, but it covers the 80% cases and i can add new tests if there are ever any defects.

Comment: So in your case, the generation of the combination of arguments is static? Does it 'discover' the components which make up a particular command what it should be running or do you have a static list of different combinations of commands? Also what would happen if the tool undergoes a haul where new commands are added, or new error codes are added? This requires manual intervention into the test utility as well to modify it?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "Does it *discover*...".  The test suite is built purposefully to test the CLI tool, and therefore the tests implicitly include knowledge of what the CLI does, the kinds of inputs it accepts.  The input is not static - the test suite uses the System.Random class to generate input, and it does so repeatedly. In some cases it generates input randomly and runs tests *repeatedly*, until some criterion for case coverage is reached. It is not a "static list of combinations" but it is also not 100% coverage, which I judged to be an impractical in my case.

Comment: As for modifying the CLI and adding error codes, following TDD, I write new tests first. I write the test that defines sets of inputs and what outputs I expect, then I write the code for the CLI, then I run the tests.

Answer (score 1):

Using a recursive grammar to generate switches is an interesting idea. If you where to try this then you would need to first write the grammar in such a way that all switches could be used, and then do a *random walk* of the grammar.
[This](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/01/28/generating-random-sentences-from-a-context-free-grammar/) provides an easy method of randomly walking a grammar and outputting the result.